# Swig and reference counted C++ classes

Tags: c++, swig, reference-counting

Many of my C++ objects implement rerfrence counting through AddRef and FreeRef methods. If FreeRef reduces the reference count to 0 then the object deletes its self.

All methods which return a reference counted object don't increment the reference. This makes it simple since a smart pointer can then simply increment the count apon receiving a pointer and decrement the count when they no longer reference it. eg:

```
template<class T> FlPtr
{
    T *p;
public:
    FlPtr(T *p=0):p(p){if(p)p->AddRef();}
    ~FlPtr(){if(p)p->FreeRef();}

    FlPtr<T>& operator =(T *newP)
    {
        if(newP)newP->AddRef();
        if(p)p->FreeRef();
        p = newP;
        return *this;
    }
    operator T*(){return p;}
};
```

I was thinking maybe if I could tell SWIG to just use my existing smart pointer internally for these objects that may work however im not sure how to do that either :(

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn34). Basically, if you have a class `Foo` and want to wrap it with a smart pointer `Bar`, you do this:

```
%ignore Foo;
class Foo {
    ...
};

class Bar {
public:
    Foo *operator->();
    ...
}
```

Now when you try to access members of a instance of `Bar`, it will internally use Foo, but this will be completely transparent.